# Argument 3 passed to MongoDB\Driver\Server::executeBulkWrite() must be an instance of MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern or null

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I got an error from mongo db, when I connect with application server through php 7.2,**

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to MongoDB\Driver\Server::executeBulkWrite() must be an instance of MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern or null, array given in /var/www/html/project/apps/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/InsertOne.php:134 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/project/apps/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/InsertOne.php(134): MongoDB\Driver\Server->executeBulkWrite('project.app_fe...', Object(MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite), Array) #1 /var/www/html/project/apps/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php(931): MongoDB\Operation\InsertOne->execute(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Server)) #2 /var/www/html/project/apps/api/appFeedback.php(75): MongoDB\Collection->insertOne(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/project/apps/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/InsertOne.php on line 134